# How to allow all alphabets/space/single quotation/dash in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to accept all alphabets and space,single quotation and dash.

I have this script :

```
$('.firstName').bind('keyup blur', function() {
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z\s]/gi, ''));
});
```

Which only accepts alphabets and spaces. Now I need to add Single Quote and dash also.

Comment: Why not just add them? `/[^a-z\s'-]/gi`?

Comment: will that be enough ? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: No idea what you mean. You say you remove all chars that are not ASCII letters and whitespace, and now, you also want to remove those that are not `'` and `-`. So, it is only logical to add them into `[...]`

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z '-]*$
```

Here is the regular expression that will start with an alphabet and can include spaces , single quotation and dash symbol.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested the above comment the regex `/[^a-z\s'-]/gi` will do the job, but I suggest the use of `input` event instead of the others `keyup blur` since it's more efficient when you track the use inputs :

```
$('.firstName').on('input', function() {
  var node = $(this);

  node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z\s'-]/gi, ''));
});
```

**NOTE :** The `bind()` method was deprecated use `on()` instead.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.firstName').on('input', function() {
  var node = $(this);

  node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z\s'-]/gi, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='firstName' />
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you:

```js
$('.firstName').bind('keyup blur', function() {
            var node = $(this);

            node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z\s'-]/gi, ''));

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='firstName' />
```

This will replace everything that is not an alphabet, space, dash and single quote.

Comment: i have this 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>